# Tex4ht not generating html tags

Tags: texmaker, tex4ht

I'm trying to generate an html document from my .tex file (I just need paragraph and link formatting, nothing fancy).

I'm using Texmaker 5.0.3, Miktex 2.9 on Windows 10, with the tex4ht package installed today.

In Texmaker, I build my .tex file with "LaTex" to generate the dvi file.
Then I go to Tools -> Export via Tex4ht, select "export to html" and run.

The run finishes without error and I can see an html file has been generated in my working folder. But when I open this html file in a browser, there is no formatting at all. When I view the source code of the page, I can see that no html tags have been added (it's just plain text).

My .tex source code is minimal:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{ }
\usepackage[margin=2.0cm]{geometry}        
\usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[style=nature, url=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{C:/library.bib}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing 

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

{\Huge Title}

\end{center}

Test paragraph~\cite{Aristotle1999} with references.

\bigskip

Test paragraph 2.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TEX.SE, could you provide an example code to try and figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: @Superuser27 I added my tex file if that's what you mean by "code" but it's almost empty, so I'm not sure it's going to help you

Comment: can you try to run the conversion in the terminal? using `make4ht filename.tex` or `htlatex filename.tex`? I get normal HTML file for your source in TL in Linux.

Comment: @michal.h21 these two commands work for me. Does it mean Texmaker is the culprit?

Comment: yes, it is possible. does texmaker print the actual command it uses for the conversion somewhere?

Comment: @michal.h21 it uses `"htlatex" "document.tex" " " " " " " -interaction=nonstopmode`

Comment: that doesn't seem wrong. I cannot test TeXmaker myself, so I don't know what is the issue. I think it would be best to contact TeXmaker developers for help. In the meantime you can use tex4ht from the command line.